# Two security groups with different permissions for the same model - Odoo

Tags: security, permissions, odoo, acl

I have a model called "banner". I am trying to create a security group "custom_sales" which will only have read access to "banner". However, I want the admin user to have all access rights.
This is what I'm trying:
security/groups.xml:

```
<record model="res.groups" id="custom_sales">
    <field name="name">Custom Sales Group</field>
    <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_admin'))]"/>
</record>
```

ir.model.access.csv:

```
access_ftrv_banner,access.ftrv.banner,model_ftrv_banner,custom_sales,1,0,0,0
```

This does create an access right of read only for custom sales users but the admin can no longer even view the banner model

Comment: because you didn't add access right on your custom model "banner" to user_admin group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first : modify security group because what you wrote will make all users in your custom group **admin role** (base.user_admin)

```
<record model="res.groups" id="custom_sales">
    <field name="name">Custom Sales Group</field>
    <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
</record>
```

second : add all access rights to admin

`access_ftrv_banner_admin,access.ftrv.banner.admin,model_ftrv_banner,base.user_admin,1,1,1,1`

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the explanation. It works! Modifying the security group so that eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"  was the issue.

Comment: Can you also suggest me how I can make inventory as read only for a particular security group that I created? I have tried but the read only rule is not being applied to the sales group. @omar ahmed

Comment: what did you mean by saying 'inventory' ?
is that inventory model or field or what ?

Comment: It is the main sales inventory which is based on product.template model basically @omar

Comment: access_product_template,access.product.template,product.model_product_template,custom_group_sales,1,0,0,0
Basically I am trying this so that sales group can read only the inventory. But it does not work like that

Comment: I am trying to create permissions for an existing Odoo model "product.template" that has several permissions already defined however in a different group. @omar ahmed

Comment: Do you want to put permission on your custom module ? ... don't forget to add module_name before model in access rights .